# SQL Server Function Timeout - Although the select statement inside the function runs in 1 second

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout, sql-function

SQL Server 2012

Can anyone shed some light on this bizare behavour?

I have a function that calls a very complicated select statement. It accepts 3 parameters

```
Select * 
from Myfunction(@CompanyId, @DivisionId, @PersonId)
```

This times out after 10 minutes.

If I take the internal SQL of the function, declare the same variables, set them to the same values and run, this takes a second to return 8 records.

If I run the function with a `@CompanyId` that does not return results, I get no rows back as expected and is returned immediately (so it's not permissions issue).

We have just inserted a lot of data in for this function to deal with, but this does not explain why the select is working and the function hangs?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a table valued function with a bunch of statements in it? This is known as a multi-statement table valued function and are almost always slower than even a scalar function. Can you share the function code? Without it the best we can do is guess.

Comment: When you say it times out, what exactly do you mean? SQL will just let it run forever. Have you checked sp_who2 when running this to check whether you have any blocking?

Comment: With performance based questions, you gotta share the code sir.

Comment: Could be parameter sniffing

Comment: Try putting  OPTION (RECOMPILE) at the end of the SELECT statement.

Comment: It is a table values function, with one select statement, that returns a table.

Comment: It times out when running from winforms application.  Yes, it does run forever (over 20 mins anyway) if I run it in SQL management studio.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.  It was an Index issue.

I found that adding a non-clustered index on one of the columns (used in one of the joins) in the function fixed this issue.  Still unsure why this worked in a stand alone select statement, but had an issue inside a function... but the index has solved it.

Thanks